# user role for display only user details not all details for other in mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a login page in mvc c# for user name and password. I want each user to be able to only access his details in mvc controller

```
[Authorize]
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private OfficeEntities db = new OfficeEntities();

    // GET: Employees

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Employee.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `HttpContext.Current.User`?

Comment: no i am looking for user login and only see his details only

Comment: Your question isn't very clear what your trying to do. Maybe you should re-word it.